# Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment doesn't return role assignments for SP representing AAD apps in OTHER tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to get all the role assignments of all Service Principals to my App registeration app?
I get only ones that are from my home tenant.

Explanation:

- I have **2 tenants: **A**, **B****.
- **My app registeration app is in tenant A**.
- There are app registerations in tenant A that has role assignments to my app registeration app.
  **But there are also Service principals in tenant A that represents app registeration in tenant B that has role assignments to my app**.

When I `Connect-AzureAD` to tenant A and run:

```
$myAppServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '$myAppRegisterationAppId'"

Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $myAppServicePrincipal.ObjectId
```

I get **only** the Service principals of the app registeration in my home tenant - A. I don't see any Service principals representing other app registerations apps in other tenants.

(I also tried running this command in tenant B but it doesn't find my app registeration app there, which is quite obvious)

Comment: This is probably because the `ObjectId` for an app registration is different than that of a service principal. What they should have in common is application id. Can you please check the values?

Comment: actually the `$myRegisterationAppObjectId` holds the object Id of the service principal that represents my aad app. Let me update my question with more code to reflect exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` returns an object of type Service Principal which has a property `ObjectId`. Shouldn't your code be like `Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $myAppServicePrincipalObjectId.ObjectId`?

Comment: yes sorry that was just me not typing all my commands right. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

The Object ID of the service principal changes from one tenant to another tenant.

[image]

[image]

**(Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '$myAppRegisterationAppId'").objectid** returns the Object ID of service principal in Tenant A.

So, **Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $myAppServicePrincipal.ObjectId** returns only the role assignments of SP in Tenant A.

If we connect to Tenant A and run the below script, it will return the role assignments of SP in tenant A.

```
$myAppServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "AppId eq '$myAppRegisterationAppId'"

Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $myAppServicePrincipal.ObjectId
```

[image]

Similarly, if we connect to Tenant B and run the same script, it will return the role assignments of SP in tenant B.

[image]

Comment: I know that, it still doesn’t answer my question on how to do that

Comment: Using Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment, we will only get the role assignments of SP in tenant A itself. Similar way, we can connect to Tenant B and use the same script mentioned in the question to return role assignments of  SP in tenant B